# Encfs error: `/bin/umount: unrecognized option `--no-canonicalize'`

Tags: troubleshooting, encfs, nas

I just installed `encfs` from source on a synology disk-station (DSM 4.1) and it seems to work fine. But when I try to `unmount` my `encfs` directory via `fusermount -u` I get the error message:

```
fusermount -u myencfstestdir
/bin/umount: unrecognized option `--no-canonicalize'
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2012-09-26 03:30:23 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: umount [OPTIONS] FILESYSTEM|DIRECTORY

Unmount file systems

Options:
-n Don't erase /etc/mtab entries
-r Try to remount devices as read-only if mount is busy
-l Lazy umount (detach filesystem)
-f Force umount (i.e., unreachable NFS server)
-d Free loop device if it has been used
```

However the directory seems to be unmounted. I can mount it with `encfs` afterwards without problems.

Should I care about this error message? If not, how can I suppress it, or even better, how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using `umount` from `util-linux` directly?

Comment: Seems to work, however the encfs manual says that one should use `fusermount -u`. So I am not sure if something may go wrong when using `umount` (I want to use it for backup purposes, so everything should work for 100%)...

Answer (score 1):

You are using BusyBox' `umount`, presumably that one doesn't understand encfs specific flags (and its `mount` might also do things wrong). Does the encfs package include `mount`/`unmount` programs? Better use those. Perhaps you need to build a BusyBox with encfs support?

Comment: I don't know if `encfs` does include `mount`/`umount` programs, but I guess it doesn't. How can I build BusyBox with `encfs` support?